# How do I create a Jacobian matrix for a large system of equations?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I would like to create a Jacobian matrix using the simplified functions below:

```
f1[a_,b_,c_]:= a^2 + b^2
f2[a_,b_,c_]:= c/2
f3[a_,b_,c_]:= b^3
```

I say simplified because in the actual code that I'm working on, there are 14 functions and hence 14 variables defined for each function, all defined as `f1,f2,...f14`. Because of the large size, I wanted to get an idea about how I could implement the following code on the wolfram site possibly using iteration:

```
JacobianMatrix[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] :=
    Outer[D, f, x] /; Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {f, x})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is way to iterate over a list of functions applying each function to the same sequence of variables.

```
funcs = {f1, f2, f3};
vars = {x, y, z};
h = Table[g @@ Sequence@vars, {g, funcs}];
JacobianMatrix[h, vars]
```

A more compact way to get the Jacobian matrix is

```
Outer[D, Through[funcs @@ Sequence@vars], vars]
```

Comment: I get an error. For `funcs`, would I have to do `{f1[a_,b_,c_],f2[a_,b_,c_],f3[a_,b_,c_]}`?

Comment: The underscore (`Blank`) is used to define functions, but not in when evaluating the functions.  So, no, don't use `Blank` in your argument list, or in your list of variables.  You may need to do something like `ClearAll` on your functions and/or variables.  Or you may want to quit the kernel and then re-evaluate your notebook.  Please describe the error in more detail.  Do you mean it doesn't work with the 3 example functions, or it doesn't work with your 14 actual functions?  Does it fail on one function in particular?  Can you add any of your functions to the question?